# W2UI grid: Checked Checkboxes not saving;

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, w2ui

I introduced two buttons on the toolbar one  'CheckAll' and the other 'UncheckAll', they are to have effect on a particular column say 'Status'  (with checkboxes) in the grid. I wrote two Javascript functions to do this.

```
function check_all(the_unchecked){
        for(i=0; i<the_unchecked.length; i++){
        the_unchecked[i].checked = true;
    }
}

function uncheck_all(the_checked){
    for(i=0; i<the_checked.length; i++){
        the_checked[i].checked = false;
    }
```

}
 The effected field:

```
{field: 'status', caption: 'Status', size: '50px', searchable: 'text', resizable: true, render: function (records) {
                    if (records.status === true) {
                        return   '<span style="background-color:#a3e9a4; width:100%;display:block;"> <input class="enable_check" type="checkbox" name="enable_check[]" value="true" checked="true"></span>';
                    } else {
                        return  '<span style="background-color:#f69988; width:100%;display:block;"> <input class="enable_check2" name="enable_check[]" value="false" type="checkbox"></span>';
                    }
                }, style: 'text-align:center'},
```

The problem is when I clicked on Save button the checked buttons are nor sent/saved to the database.

What I want is when CheckAll is clicked it checks all checkboxes in the column Status of the fetched rows, then 'Save' persist all the changes to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way would be to attach checkAll and uncheckAll to the grid itself. Then it is easier to use it. I have also modified the render function to save status back to the grids records. So, this is how you can add:

```
{ field: 'status', caption: 'Status', size: '50px', 
    render: function (record) {
        return '<div style="text-align: center">'+
           '    <input type="checkbox" ' + (record.status ? 'checked' : '') + 
           '        onclick="var obj = w2ui[\''+ this.name + '\']; obj.get('+ record.recid +').status = this.checked;">'+
           '</div>';
    }
}
```

Then I have added these functions to the grid

```
checkAll: function () {
    this.set({ status: true });
},
uncheckAll: function () {
    this.set({ status: false }); 
},
getAllChecked: function () {
    return this.find({ status: true });
}
```

Which you can add when you define grid's columns. After that, you can call it this way:

```
w2ui[grid_name].checkAll();
// OR
w2ui[grid_name].uncheckAll();
```

However, you will need to get all records ids to submit it to the server, use getAllChecked for this. On the second thought, I do not think you need to define those functions, as they are so short. Just call them directly when you need them.

NOTE: you might consider using grid.show.selectColumn = true. See http://w2ui.com/web/docs/w2grid.show